# How to center the barplot title horizontally in the whole image using vanilla R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, centering

In R, using the function `barplot` gives me the title centered horizontally over the plot area, not over the whole image.

```
par(mar=c(3,13,4,2))
barplot(10:1,horiz=T,main='Centralized title',las=1,names.arg=rep(paste0(letters,collapse=''),10))
```

[image: R's default barplot]

How can I have the title centered on the whole image instead, like in the image below?

[image: R's barplot with title centered in the image]

I know I can fiddle with `adj` parameter, but it's based on trial and error, the correct value changes with font size, among other problems. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set an outer margin
2. Use `mtext`

```
par(mar=c(3,13,0,2), oma=c(0,0,3,0))
barplot(10:1,horiz=T,las=1,names.arg=rep(paste0(letters,collapse=''),10))
mtext('Centralized title', outer = TRUE)
```

[image]